# Javascript: function.prototype.method

Tags: javascript

I guess most of you have seen the following code snippet:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this;
};
```

I also know that it will affect all functions since they are all objects created by Function so that they can access method named "method", however I am confused why Function itself also can also access "method" like following:

```
Function.method('test', function () {return 1;});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edorka's answer is correct: Function is its own constructor (i.e. "parent").

```
Function.constructor;  // function Function() { [native code] }
```

Normally you **can't** do what you're doing. For example, this won't work:

```
f = function () {};
f.prototype.a = 5;
f.a;  // undefined
```

This kind of thing only works if you use a function as a constructor, like so:

```
f = function () {};
f.prototype.a = 5;
g = new f();
g.a;  // 5
```

But Function is weird, it is the constructor for all functions and is also a function itself, so it templates its properties off **its own** prototype. Hence you can call `Function.method()` in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Because `Function` is itself a function:

```
typeof Function === 'function'
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Function.prototype
```

And you can see it being called as a function (a form of indirect `eval`):

```
Function('return 1+2')() === 3
```

All that as defined [in the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.3).

zerkms asked in [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446361/javascript-function-prototype-method#comment25345160_17446387):

> Which came first - the Function object or the Function prototype?

We have to understand that what's exposed to us, the puny programmers, is different than what's represented internally. This can be exemplified by overriding the `Array` constructor (tip: don't try this while writing an answer, you'll get a lot of errors):

```
new Array(0, 1, 2); //gives you [0, 1, 2]
Array = function () { return [4] };
new Array(0, 1, 2); //gives you [4]
//however,
[0, 1, 2] //will always give you [0, 1, 2]
```

This is because of [a section in the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.4) (a bit down, in the "semantics" section):

> Let array be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression `new Array()` where `Array` is the standard built-in constructor with that name.

Using the array literal (or array initializer as the spec calls it) you *ensure* that you use the *built-in* Array constructor.

Why did I give this example? First of all, because it's a fun example. Second, to demonstrate how what we do and what's actually done are different. To answer zerkms, the Function object most likely came first, but that was not the first function. We don't have access to that built-in function.

Comment: "zerkms asked" --- it was actually a joke referred to a "chicken vs egg" problem :-)

Comment: @zerkms Of course, and in this case, the chicken was actually brought to us by a more sentient being. Problem forever solved now?

Answer (score 1):

because new functions are using the Function's prototype, Functions method is using his own prototype methods too.

If you modify one of this methods or attributes and it belonged to a "parent" prototype all the other objects using this prototype will be affected.

Some literacy related to this strange subject: http://www.packtpub.com/article/using-prototype-property-in-javascript

Comment: Which came first - the `Function` object or the `Function` prototype?

Comment: the prototype, if the object itself can't get de method or attribute if asks it to its prototype , or prototype's prototype....

Comment: I just think for `Function itself, it should be the object of Object, thus it will only look for the prototype of Object instead of `Function itself.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following constructor function object:

```
var Construct = function () { };
```

And a prototype shared function:

```
Construct.prototype.hello = function (name) { console.log("Hello " + name); };
```

Now if you create a `new` object from the constructor, this gets the shared member function:

```
var c = new Construct();
c.hello("World");
```

The same as `c` is `instanceof Construct Object`, also any

- `function` is `instanceof Function` and `instanceof Object`,
- `Function` itself is `instanceof Function` and `Object`,
- `Construct` is `instanceof Function Object` and also
- `Object` is `instanceof Function Object`.

Every `function` statement and operator is a literal for a native `new Function`.
Every `{ }` literal is a native `new Object`.

Objects created `new` by a `constructor` get the members of the `constructor.prototype`.
Objects can have any member for themselves, only members of prototypes get shared.

Comment: I just think for `Function itself, it should be the object of `Object, thus it will only look for the prototype of `Object instead of `Function itself.

Comment: @user2546240 it is. don't confuse with typeof's results. just try instanceof. because typeof is a string it can't say function and object the same time. instanceof is more accurate because it knows that function is both object of Function and object of Object.